# TouchDB - CouchbaseLite Libraries?

Tags: android, touchdb

I have decided to made my application using TouchDB for Android, which is the light version of CouchDB for Mobile Platform. I am able to find sample projects for this on the github but I did not find all the libraries needed for implementing TouchDB in Android.
https://github.com/couchbaselabs

I could not find the jar files for the classes like CBLURLStreamHandlerFactory and CBLServer.

Can anybody list the libraries to download and include in TouchDB based Android Project?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link.

It has TouchDB-Android and TouchDB-Android-Ektorp. Import these folders as Libraries in your project and then you are done.

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android/wiki/Getting-Started

1. You need to make these two Projects(TouchDB-Android, TouchDB-Android-Ektorp) in Eclipse as libraries by checking option "is Library".
2. and then include them in your main project.

Answer (score 1):

Your posting is from July 20, 2013 - but TouchDB is now an obsolete product. It was renamed to Couchbase-Lite. The rename was discussed publicly as far back as January 2013.

This might explain why you are having troubles with newer Android environments, etc.

Couchbase-Lite for Android is here: 
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android

Comment: Thanks.
Actually they have moved this project to Couchbase-Lite repo. Further changes will be made in this repo. The project that is given for the sample is based on the Android Studio platform. 

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android
with important note:
this repository has been superceded by Couchbase Lite Android. Please switch to that repository instead and refer to Moving from TouchDB to Couchbase Lite for more information.

But it is still behind iOS. If you find any running project for the Android using Eclipse then please post the link here.
Thanks a lot.